# Google Custom Search Work with Dynamic Web Site (i.e. Struts 2 + Tiles 2 with Spring)?

Tags: java, struts2, google-search

I'm new to google custom search and I want to include that in my website which is built using Struts 2 + Tiles 2 + Spring . Since the contents are generated dynamically from a database, I'm wondering whether google custom search will be able to index and retrieve the data? I guess it probably can, but I'm not sure how it looks into the database (where the contents of the page exist) and index the page.

Is there any modifications or additions of some code to make google crawler or search to access my website?

Can anyone give me some idea or point me to a right direction? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can find help here:
 https://forums.zoho.com/topic/using-google-custom-search-to-search-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to get the Google crawler to index your website, most notably by editing the [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file in your website's root.

Once that is done, request Google to index your site: [by entering your URL here](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl)

The Google Custom Search Engine will load the search results, just as though you had performed a Google search yourself, but embedded within your own website's page. You can set parameters to the search by logging into Google, such as restricting the `site:`'s that are searched (maybe limited to your own domain).